# render_to_response concatenate URL to the current URL

Tags: python, django

I have a view to delete a record when clicking an anchor in index page.I wanna redirect to current page after running this view.in urls.py:

```
(r'^airAgency/(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/tour/delete/(?P<tour_id>\d+)/$','airAgency.views.deletetour'),
(r'^airAgency/(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$','airAgency.views.index'),
```

in views.py:

```
def deletetour(request,key,tour_id):
   tour=Tour.objects.get(pk=tour_id)
   tour.delete()
   top5news=News.objects.filter(User__agentposition__AgentCode__id=agn.id).order_by('-ActionDate')[:5]
   return render_to_response('airAgency/index.html/',{'top5news':top5news},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

imagine now browser is in this address:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane
```

when I click on anchor that redirect me to deletetour view,after deleting recored,browser locate in this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane/tour/delete/4/airAgency/index.html/
```

but I wanna again redirect to first url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane
```

Note that I need RequestContext object,too.I mean HttpResponseRedirect isn't good for me.

tnx in advance

Comment: Why HttpResponseRedirect isn't good for your? You say you need to redirect, this is what HttpResponseRedirect is used for.

Comment: because I need context_instance=RequestContext(request),too. I can not pass this object when using HttpResponseRedirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to use `HttpResponseRedirect`, try this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in a handler for another url, you can't change the url without redirecting.  If you need to maintain state into the original url when you get back to it, encode it into get parameters of the url you are redirecting back to.

Also, not sure if you are already doing this, but the deletion of the record should really be handled in a POST not a get.

Hope this helps!

Comment: U mean I should handle it into the index view?how can I do this?what's th right way?

Comment: Note that I need to send some objects like 'top5news' when redirecting to current page.

Comment: if you need context_instance, presumably theres some finite set of variables *from* context_instance you need to render airAgency/index.html properly after deletion, right?  You can't include arbitrary python variables with the redirect, but you can individually encode variables with the url, e.g return HttpResponseRedirect("/path?" + urllib.urlencode({'deletedname': 'thename'}))

Answer (score 1):

If you need RequestContext object just for showing some delete success message you can use
[django.contrib.messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) framework.